# wget and vnc viewer give error about buffer space and chrome can't browse

Tags: windows-7

The errors I got were-

Chrome wasn't loading the pages..

I tried wget

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuwin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-11-13 20:42:22--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.230.116, 74.125.230.113, 74.125.230.114, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.116|:80... failed: No buffer space available.
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.113|:80... failed: No buffer space available.
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.114|:80... failed: No buffer space available.
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.115|:80... failed: No buffer space available.
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.230.112|:80... failed: No buffer space available.
Retrying.
```

I tried to access a drive on my LAN

```
C:\>w:
The name limit for the local computer network adapter card was exceeded.
```

VNCviewer.exe trying to access another comp on my LAN said

> connect: an operation on a socket could not be performed because the
>   system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a process using too many handles. In my case googledrivesync.

This was visiile in task manager under 'performance' I saw about 186,000 handles in use.  I made the handle column visible in task manager. Saw it was a googledrivesync.exe process using 400K RAM but 186K or 176K handles.

I end tasked it and then browsing was fine.